# Turning responsive web app to app?

Tags: java, web-applications, responsive-design, mobile-application

I have a responsive web application that uses Spring mvc controller for handling client requests. I am using jsp's as views.

Now I'd like to contruct the mobile app with same code base. I heard people saying that we need to expose the services as RESTful webservices 
to send the content back to browser. Is it true?

Per mine understanding there should be no need of this as ultimately mobile app will also send the data by http and I should be able to receive/send the
data back from servlet/controller. Am I wrong?

Also I see some site   offering which just the  url of website and gives you back the app. Is it not the scurity threat where I can provide the url of famous site
say ebay and convert to app with mine custom name and upload to playstore. I know  there must be some catch here but not sure what's that?

Comment: If the existing web application is responsive, meaning it's already mobile friendly, then why do you need a mobile app?

Comment: It's not a good idea to ask several questions in one, but if you'd like to, you have at least to link some examples of the services you mention in the third question.